# JSF does not report undefined beans

Tags: java, jsf, el, javabeans

I started to learn Java, JSF2 and JPA2 and used "Pet Catalog" example project to start with. I use Eclipse + Glassfish.

So I have JSF view page with following line:

```
<h:outputText value="Item #{catalog.pagingInfo.firstItem + 1} .. #{cataloTYPO.pagingInfo.lastItem} of #{catalog.pagingInfo.itemCount}"/>
```

cataloTYPO does not exist, it's not a bean, not class, nothing. The problem is that JSF seems to be perfectly happy with it and outputs "Item 1 .. of 29" I'd expect it would raise exception or at least write the problem to log, but nothing happens.

I tried to google this problem but nobody seems to have it.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: alternatively, is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not specific to JSF. This is specific to EL (those `#{}` things). It's designed to be nullsafe. If nothing is available in the scope, i.e. it is `null`, then it will just take no further actions. It prints nothing and no `NullPointerException` will be thrown. This is particularly useful in cases where an `empty` situation is allowed.

If you want to raise exceptions or warn reports anyway, then you'll have to write your own `ELResolver` which does that when the resolved value turns out to be `null`.  A nice article about implementing an own [`ELResolver`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) for JSF can be found [here](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/thoughts/frameworks/JSF.Techniques-ELResolvers.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Given that Java is generally error intolerant (compared to e.g. PHP) this was quite unexpected for me. I think that this behavior is appropriate for production stage but not so good for development stage ...

Comment: EL is basically a whole language at its own.